# Cassandra java driver UDT Mapping

Tags: java, cassandra

So I have a UDT in Cassandra Database:

```
CREATE TYPE cs4224.OrderLine (
    OL_I_ID int,
    OL_DELIVERY_D timestamp,
    OL_AMOUNT float,
    OL_SUPPLY_W_ID int,
    OL_QUANTITY int,
    OL_DIST_INFO varchar
);
```

When I query for this, I can get UDTValue but I am not sure how can I map to a UDTClass as I am using Cassandra Java Driver 2.2.0rc3

In 2.1, there is some instruction like this [tutorial](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/mappingUdts.html). But it seems this(UDTMapper) is removed or not yet added in 2.2.0. How can do the same thing or just to achieve the same effect?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I do not have to the UDTMapper at all in 2.2.0rc3. Basically there is a UDTValue class that I can make use of to get whatever value I want by using getInt or similar methods. A code sample is below:

```
Map<Integer, UDTValue> ols = row.getMap("o_ols", Integer.class, UDTValue.class);
for (Integer key: ols.keySet()) {
     UDTValue ol = ols.get(key);
     olIId = ol.getInt("ol_i_id");
     olQuantity = ol.getInt("ol_quantity");
     olDistInfo = ol.getString("ol_dist_info");
     olSupplyWId = ol.getInt("ol_supply_w_id");
     olAmount = ol.getFloat("ol_amount");
     olSum += olAmount;
     newOrderLine = orderLineType.newValue()
         .setInt("OL_I_ID", olIId)
         .setTimestamp("ol_delivery_d", new Timestamp(now.getTime()))
         .setFloat("ol_amount", olAmount)
         .setInt("ol_supply_w_id", olSupplyWId)
         .setInt("ol_quantity", olQuantity)
         .setString("ol_dist_info", olDistInfo);
     orderLines.put(key, newOrderLine);
 }
```

hope this helps others as well.